# How to add placeholder for contact form7 for dropdown?

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I tried adding placeholder similar to the given for **ContactNumber** for my drop down **Outlet** but it doesn't appear.

Code-

```
<div class="form-group form-icon-group">
    <i class="fa fa-phone" > </i> [tel* ContactNumber /8 class:form-control placeholder "Contact Number *"]
</div>
<div class="form-group form-icon-group">
<i class="fa fa-food" > </i> [select Outlet id:outlet class:form-control "-- Select Outlet--" "Pasir Ris" "Thomson"]
</div>
```

Tried adding `first_as_label "Preferred outlet?"` so this displays as ordinary drop down values.

Rest all of the fields do show the placeholder,any other way to give placeholder for drop down?

Comment: You can use the placeholder option in the following types of form tags: text, email, url, tel, textarea, number, range, date, and captchar. [cf7 placeholder](http://contactform7.com/setting-placeholder-text/)

Comment: so for drop down we don't have any other choice?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

to answer the question: this is not possible.

AFAIK, (HTMLwise) there's no way to add a placeholder to select tags.

A lot of devs I know however tend to use `disabled selected` combination for the option...

```html
<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="ydasdas">ydasdas</option>
    <option value="dasda">dasda</option>
    <option value="ydagfdsdas">ydagfdsdas</option>
    <option value="ewefsdf">ewefsdf</option>
</select>
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9amo84jd/)

I have checked CF7's source code (version 4.3.1), and there's no easy way we can achieve this html format.

You can go the hard way by removing `wpcf7_add_shortcode_select` action on `wpcf7_init` and add yours instead.

Comment: This answer really should be removed, accepted or not it's incorrect, and it isn't like it's a very old answer, it was supplied on the same day as the correct one was.

Answer (score 134):

Contrary to what the accepted answer suggests, it actually is possible and built into Contact Form 7. Here's the actual [list of options `[select]` holds](http://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/#select). Pretty much you would define the first option to be the placeholder using `first_as_label`:

```
[select* Test first_as_label "Placeholder" "Option 1" "Option 2"]
```

While it won't traditionally look like a placeholder, if it's required the user won't be able to select the placeholder and send the form - this forces the user to select any of the other options.

Comment: Thanks for the help.i already tried `first_as_label` but as you said it didn't look similar to other placeholder values.

Comment: This is a decent solution.  And it does work properly - the form doesn't send if you try using the first option.  To format the first option, just target the select box (i.e. `.wpcf7 select[name="menu-70"] { color:#aaa; }`.  Then you can make the options darker by targeting the options (i.e. `.wpcf7 select[name="menu-70"] option { color:#333; }`. The first option is highighted on focus, so unless you want to change this part, the solution works great.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why anyone would want a select option to look like a placeholder unless I am missing something a simple --Select an option-- is what most people expect to see. Thank you very much for saving me from looking through the documentation myself!

Comment: Now this option does not work on mac. The style is applied from the select. Options are just a representation of the content. The text. They are not the styled element.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Great!